# Assigning value to underlying properties of source for DataGridView from DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcombobox

I have a datagridview that is assigned to a BindingList of CustomerPricing and within CustomerPricing there are fields such as the product name, the price, quantity desired and whether this item is taxable or not. Within the datagridview I have a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn that has as it's data source a List of Product. A product has as it's fields the name, price and whether it is taxable.

The client's wish is that once a product as been selected, the price value is automatically displayed in the DataGridView and from a developer's point of view, the Taxable property is updated as well (this will not be displayed).

Does anyone have any idea of how to accomplish this? I've tried using the EditControlShowing event and assigning values directly to the cells, but that doesn't help to update the properties of the underlying object that are not displayed. I made a hack, which works but is slow and would only like to use if there isn't a more accepted way of doing it.

Thanks